# Not able to install padwalker on osx 10.6.8

Tags: macos, perl

I want to install padwalker on my mac so that i can use it in eclipse(helios)

$ make -version is 3.81

Installing PadWalker from cpan & directly via the make command gives me the following error

```
PadWalker.xs: In function ‘fetch_from_stash’:
PadWalker.xs:179: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
    lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/xB/xBJ-fz33GWibK4FbV4AAwk+++TI/-Tmp-//ccl9TEXl.out (No such file or directory)
make: *** [PadWalker.o] Error 2
  ROBIN/PadWalker-1.98.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 ROBIN/PadWalker-1.98.tar.gz                  : make NO
```

I am sorry but i really looked over the web for answers but have not found any.
Someone suggested to use cpanm, but that too is of no use

Comment: I can't really help you with this, but I see that the install is failing because of a missing "`ccl9TEXl.out`" file.  Why not delete that entire folder and try installing again?  Also, will padwalker even work on a relatively old MacOS 10.6.8 system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a dirty trick.
With cpan, i am still not able to install it.

However i downloaded PadWalker-1.98.tar.gz

Opened Makefile.PL and removed the line MIN_PERL_VERSION => "5.008001",

I did $ perl Makefile.PL

With reference to https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=69506

I opened the generated Makefile & removed all instances of '-arch ppc' in Makefile.

finally
$make
&
$make install

Now i am able to view the local variables in eclipse